# Creating a cumulative sum in column based on a specific value

Tags: r, function, sum

I have a data as shown below

```
 field_pointpath                             value  value1
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03x6KSF_11xaP_ACTACC    19530   0
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03x6KSF_11xaP_ACTACC    19540   #N/A
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03x6KSF_11xaP_ACTACC    19545   #N/A
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03x6KSF_11xaP_ACTACC    19550   #N/A
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03x6KSF_11xaP_ACTACC    19570   #N/A
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03x6KSF_11xaP_ACTACC    15943   0
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03x6KSF_11xaP_ACTACC    15944   #N/A
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03x6KSF_11xaP_ACTACC    15945   #N/A
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03x6KSF_11xaP_ACTACC    15950   #N/A
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03x6KSF_11xaP_ACTACC    15955   #N/A
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03x6KSF_11xaP_ACTACC    15960   #N/A
```

I want to create a function in R such that it identifies a specific variable in `field_pointpath` and calculate column `value1`

for example: for all repeated value in column `field_pointpath` `'C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03x6KSF_11xaP_ACTACC'`

```
value1 = (19540-19530)+0
```

and so on till `'C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03x6KSF_11xaP_ACTACC'` ends and for `'C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03x6KSF_11xaP_ACTACC'` it should start again

so the answer should be

```
   field_pointpath                         value    value1
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03x6KSF_11xaP_ACTACC    19530   0
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03x6KSF_11xaP_ACTACC    19540   10
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03x6KSF_11xaP_ACTACC    19545   15
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03x6KSF_11xaP_ACTACC    19550   20
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03x6KSF_11xaP_ACTACC    19570   40
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03x6KSF_11xaP_ACTACC    15943   0
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03x6KSF_11xaP_ACTACC    15944   1
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03x6KSF_11xaP_ACTACC    15945   2
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03x6KSF_11xaP_ACTACC    15950   7
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03x6KSF_11xaP_ACTACC    15955   12
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03x6KSF_11xaP_ACTACC    15960   17
```

I hope I am able to explain my problem properly
Please members kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by the cumulative sum of logical vector (`value1==0`) or by `field_pointpath`, we get the difference of value, concatenate it with 0 and get the cumulative sum

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, valueN := cumsum(c(0, diff(value))), cumsum(value1==0)]
#setDT(df1)[, valueN := cumsum(c(0, diff(value))), field_pointpath]
df1
#                             field_pointpath value value1 valueN
# 1: C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03x6KSF_11xaP_ACTACC 19530      0      0
# 2: C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03x6KSF_11xaP_ACTACC 19540   #N/A     10
# 3: C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03x6KSF_11xaP_ACTACC 19545   #N/A     15
# 4: C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03x6KSF_11xaP_ACTACC 19550   #N/A     20
# 5: C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03x6KSF_11xaP_ACTACC 19570   #N/A     40
# 6: C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03x6KSF_11xaP_ACTACC 15943      0      0
# 7: C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03x6KSF_11xaP_ACTACC 15944   #N/A      1
# 8: C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03x6KSF_11xaP_ACTACC 15945   #N/A      2
# 9: C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03x6KSF_11xaP_ACTACC 15950   #N/A      7
#10: C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03x6KSF_11xaP_ACTACC 15955   #N/A     12
#11: C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03x6KSF_11xaP_ACTACC 15960   #N/A     17
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @akrun 'code' setDT(df1)[, valueN := cumsum(c(0, diff(value))), field_pointpath] worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The below illustrates a way to do it in base R without the need for other packages. First I create some toy data which looks like your problem.

```
# Create toy data
dat <- data.frame(ID = LETTERS[rep(1:2, c(4,6))], col1 = 1:10+9000, col2 = NA)
dat$col2[c(1, 5)] <- 0
print(dat)
#   ID col1 col2
#1   A 9001    0
#2   A 9002   NA
#3   A 9003   NA
#4   A 9004   NA
#5   B 9005    0
#6   B 9006   NA
#7   B 9007   NA
#8   B 9008   NA
#9   B 9009   NA
#10  B 9010   NA
```

Overwrite the `col2` column:

```
dat$col2 <- do.call(c, tapply(dat$col1, dat$ID, FUN=function(x) cumsum(c(0, diff(x)))))
print(dat)
#   ID col1 col2
#1   A 9001    0
#2   A 9002    1
#3   A 9003    2
#4   A 9004    3
#5   B 9005    0
#6   B 9006    1
#7   B 9007    2
#8   B 9008    3
#9   B 9009    4
#10  B 9010    5
```

Comment: For your last line, you could replace `do.call(c,` with `unlist(`.